# Can't tell if Prebid CPM Adjustment is working

Tags: prebid.js

I'm trying to use CPM adjustment to create an even playing field between my header bidding partners, some of which provide bids in net and some in gross.

I've set it up, following the documentation on the Prebid website, but I don't think it's working.

When I use the `pbjs_debug=true` URL parameter and look in the console, I see no evidence that the bids are being adjusted.

Do I have it set up wrong? Or is there a better way to verify whether or not the CPMs are getting adjusted?

```
<script>
  var PREBID_TIMEOUT = 1500;

  var adUnits = [{
    code: 'div-gpt-ad-1487305430432-0',
    mediaTypes: {
      banner: {
        sizes: [[300, 250]],
      },
    },
    bids: [
      {
        /* **snip** */
      }],
  }];

  var pbjs = pbjs || {};
  pbjs.que = pbjs.que || [];

</script>
<!-- Prebid Config Section END -->

<!-- Prebid Boilerplate Section START. No Need to Edit. -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/prebid.1.20.0.js" async></script>


<script>
  var googletag = googletag || {};
  googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
  });

  pbjs.bidderSettings = [
    {
      districtm: {
        bidCpmAdjustment: function(bidCpm) {
          return bidCpm * 0.85;
        },
      },
    }];

  pbjs.que.push(function() {
    pbjs.addAdUnits(adUnits);
    //  pbjs.setPriceGranularity('low');
    const customConfigObject = {
      'buckets': [{
        'precision': 2,  //default is 2 if omitted - means 2.1234 rounded to 2 decimal places = 2.12
        'min': 0,
        'max': 14,
        'increment': 0.01,
      }],
    };

    //set custom config objec
    pbjs.setConfig({ priceGranularity: customConfigObject });

    pbjs.requestBids({
      bidsBackHandler: sendAdserverRequest,
    });

  });

  function sendAdserverRequest() {
    if (pbjs.adserverRequestSent) {
      return;
    }
    pbjs.adserverRequestSent = true;
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
      pbjs.que.push(function() {
        pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync();
        googletag.pubads().refresh();
      });
    });
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    sendAdserverRequest();
  }, PREBID_TIMEOUT);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the below code on the console:

`pbjs.bidderSettings.{{bidder_code}}.bidCpmAdjustment(100)`

In your case the bidder_code can be 'districtm'. This will return 85, meaning 85%.

You can also verify in bid responses by running:
`pbjs.getBidResponses()`

Here you can see the netRevenue as false if for that particular bidder the bidcpmadjustment is not 100%.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you! Although I'm not sure about what you say about `netRevenue`, in my bidder responses, this is always set to true, regardless of any bid CPM adjustment.